# How to properly incorporate duck-typing to return original type?

Tags: python, numpy, duck-typing

I really hope this isn't a duplicate.  I tried to search for my question and I couldn't seem to find it.

So I have a fairly simple function that converts feet to meters:

```
def feetToMeters(val):
    return numpy.array(val) * 0.3048
```

This works nicely and accepts ints, floats, arrays, and lists.  However, if I put in a list (instead of a numpy array), I'd like to have a list returned.  So I wrote this:

```
def feetToMeters(val):
    try:
        return val * 0.3084
    except TypeError:
        return [0.3084 * v for v in val]
```

(Alternatively I could use `return list(numpy.array(val) * 0.3084)` for the last line if I want to use `numpy` here, which I don't know if that really matters.)

Is this the best way to incorporate duck-typing here so that I can avoid the use of the `type` function?  Originally I tried `AttributeError`, but it didn't work.  Still, I am weary about `TypeError` even though it seems to work.

Would it be sacrilegious to use `if type(val) is list` instead?

Comment: Your new version returns `float`s when giving it an `int`.

Comment: Sorry, when I said types I meant numpy array --> numpy array, list --> list.  I'll edit it to be clearer.

Comment: @BrenBarn, not sure what you mean because when I put in a numpy array I'm receiving a numpy array back and when I put in a list I receive a list.

Comment: @nullpointer: why is it important to return a list? A NumPy array has most of the properties of a Python list; `len`, iteration, indexing, etc.

Comment: It's actually not all that important.  It's just something I thought of and wondered what the best solution to it would be.  So in a nutshell, because I'm curious to see what the solution would be.

Comment: @nullpointer: the best solution, IMHO, to just always return a NumPy array. While a workaround for the specific case of `list` is possible, returning the same type that you got passed in is not possible in general since you don't always now how to construct a value of that type.

Comment: @larmans, I agree with you, though I was wondering how to go about it if for some reason I really needed to return the same type.

Comment: @nullpointer: I once wrote a class that had to do that, because it constructed potentially large mappings so that doing a conversion after the call was too expensive. The only general solution that I found was to let the client pass in a constructor function as an argument (with `dict` as the default value).

Comment: Even if nobody can think of a good reason to distinguish numpy.array from list, it's not that hard to imagine wanting to distinguish, say, numpy.array from a lazy sequence of some kind, so you can call feetToMeters(xrange(1, 1<<31) without spinning for a few minutes until you run out of memory… Of course that's not exactly the same question as this, but it's close enough that the same discussions will mostly apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would it be sacrilegious to use `if type(val) is list` instead?

Yes, because it doesn't work for subclasses of list. If you want to go this way, at least do `isinstance(val, list)`. Here's a solution that treats lists specially, and convert everything else (including scalars and tuples) to NumPy arrays:

```
def feetToMeters(feet):
    meters = np.asarray(feet) * 0.3048
    return list(meters) if isinstance(feet, list) else meters
```

Note that:

- passing an instance of a subclass of `list` will cause a plain `list` to be returned;
- passing a list of lists will cause a list of NumPy arrays to be returned.

You could extend this to handle more types specially, but in general, for each type to be handled, you need to write more code as you need to know how to construct that type. Therefore, this kind of type conversion is usually left to client code.

Comment: Thanks for all of the research.  I hadn't thought of list of lists!

Comment: better yet: `return a.tolist() if isinstance(a,list)`. that will correctly handle lists of lists.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already use numpy I would avoid using exceptions here with something like

```
def feetToMeters(val):
    if numpy.isscalar(val):
        return val * 0.3084
    else:
        return numpy.array(val) * 0.3048
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, though I didn't realize it.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually...  This returns a numpy array when a list is the input.  I'd like a list back in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Catching TypeError is dangerous since it could be caused by many things besides a list. I would generally use isinstance(val, list) for this purpose.

Comment: I thought it felt very dangerous.  Somewhere I thought that `isinstance` and `type` were to be avoided, so I was trying to get around them, though I think you're right.  Thanks!

Comment: There are some situations when isinstance should be avoided; I don't think this is really one of them. If you wanted to allow _any_ iterable to be passed as val and interpreted like a list, then obviously you'd need a different approach -- hasattr(val, '__iter__') might work.

Comment: @nullpointer if you're using `isinstance`, you might-as-well use `Iterable` (from `collections`), instead of `list`: `isinstance(val, Iterable)`

Comment: @Luke, `hasattr([], 'iter')` is `False`, `iter` is a built-in, not (typically) a method.

Comment: @AdamWagner: `numpy.array` does not work on arbitrary iterables. I believe it requires a `Sequence`.

Comment: Adam--I typed iter with underscores but SO decided that meant bold text :/

Comment: @Luke, ahh sorry... comments get me on that sort of thing too.

Comment: @larsman Noted.  I'm not too familiar with numpy, I figured I could've got a little more generic (or restrictive, I guess) on the collections type, but I wasn't sure if it was necessary.

Comment: @Luke, you need (backslash) \__iter__

Answer (score 0):

The trick is that you are trying to support scalars and sequences - maybe something like this would work for you:

```
def feetToMeters(val):
    try:
        return type(val)(val * 0.3048)
    except TypeError:
        return type(val)(v*0.3048 for v in val)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this return an integer if the input is an integer?  Which wouldn't be super useful because it would round down and might cause my answer to be zero if it should be 0.3084.  I think that I phrased the question badly; what I meant is I want a list when I input a list and I want a numpy array when I input a numpy array.  Sorry I was unclear.